# Sort 2D points in a clockwise manner

Tags: python

I want to sort a point cloud clockwise-ly. They are somewhat ordered (i.e. they aren't random points, they actually form a closed loop in the shape of an airfoil). However, this closed loop isn't necessarily convex.

This is what I have so far. It kinda works but it still weirds out at certain points.

It breaks the points in small groups and sorts them (according to their angle w.r.t. the group's center of gravity), and then sorts these groups w.r.t. the angle of center of gravity of the whole point cloud.

```
def sort_clockwise_full(Array, format_output = "numpy"):

    Array = np.array(Array)
    n = 5
    aux_lst = []
    
    CGX_global = np.mean(Array[:,0])
    CGY_global = np.mean(Array[:,1])

    for i in range(int(len(Array)/n)):

        # breaks the array in n parts
        try:
            aux_arr = Array[n*i:n*(i+1),:]
        except IndexError:
            aux_arr = Array[n*i+n:,:]

        # calculates these parts' CoG
        COG_x = np.mean(aux_arr[:,0])
        COG_y = np.mean(aux_arr[:,1])

        # calculates the angle of each point w.r.t. the CoG of this part
        angles = np.arctan2((aux_arr[:,1] - COG_y),(aux_arr[:,0] - COG_x))
        angles = np.array(angles).reshape((aux_arr.shape[0], 1))*180/np.pi

        # sorts the full_aux_arr according to this angle 
        full_aux_arr = np.concatenate((aux_arr, angles),axis = 1)
        full_aux_arr = full_aux_arr[full_aux_arr[:, 2].argsort()][:,0:2]

        # calculates each part's CoG angle w.r.t. global CoG
        CG_angle = np.arctan2((COG_y - CGY_global),(COG_x - CGX_global))
        aux_lst.append([full_aux_arr, CG_angle])
  
    # sorts the parts according to each part's CoG angle w.r.t. global CoG
    idxs_lst = np.array([i[1] for i in aux_lst]).argsort()
    aux_lst_sorted = [aux_lst[i] for i in idxs_lst]
    
    # writes sorted points to end_arr
    end_arr = []
    for points in aux_lst_sorted:
        for point in points[0]:
            end_arr.append(point)
    end_arr = np.array(end_arr)

    return end_arr
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How to sort a point cloud in a clockwise manner, it's right there

Comment: And the answer is also already right there, take some point in the middle and sort the difference vectors by their angles.

Comment: This doesn't work because the geometry isn't necessarily convex. This ends up picking points out of order in the concave region

Comment: @Lucas P, do you know anything about the orientation of this aerofoil? If the angle of attack is 0 then the leftmost point will be the leading edge and the rightmost will be the trailing edge. The suction surface will probably be convex (or you wouldn't have lift), so you could pick this off clockwise from the leading edge. Once you know whether a point is on the suction surface or pressure surface then you can simply sort them left to right or right to left.

Comment: I did try something like this, but it's not that simple due to some geometrical peculiarities of this airfoil. Even after I rotate the AoA back to 0, it still can't be separated in upper/lower surfaces (I can't go into too much detail, I'm afraid). Thanks for the effort, though

Comment: Do you have any information about the order in which the points are contained in the input? If they describe some shape, they presumably were not inserted in the input array randomly to begin with. Perhaps they are even already in the correct order and you don't have to do anything?

Comment: The points are generally ordered (i.e. most parts are clockwise already), but some are inverted (ccw instead of cw), but the all the points are thrown in a file, inverted or not.